# LOEclipse, how to create an OptionsPage in a openoffice extension?

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I've been working in a extension for openoffice, I'm using LOEclipse ( [Libreoffice starter extension](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension)) to create it. I'm trying to create a OptionsPage in Tools/Options in LibreOffice.

This is my OptionsDialog.xcu file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<oor:component-data oor:name="OptionsDialog" oor:package="org.openoffice.Office" xmlns:oor="http://openoffice.org/2001/registry" xmlns:xs="http://www.w2.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <node oor:name="Nodes">
    <node oor:name="org.libreoffice.example.InfoPage" oor:op="fuse">
      <prop oor:name="Label">
        <value>Some Label</value>
      </prop>
      <prop oor:name="AllModules">
        <value>true</value>
      </prop>
      <prop oor:name="OptionsPage">
        <value>%origin%/../../../../../dialog/InfoDialog.xdl</value>
      </prop>

      <node oor:name="Leaves">
        <node oor:name="org.libreoffice.example.OptionsPage" oor:op="fuse">
          <prop oor:name="Id">
            <value>org.libreoffice.example.OptionsPage</value>
          </prop>
          <prop oor:name="Label">
            <value>Some Label</value>
          </prop>
          <prop oor:name="OptionsPage">
            <value>%origin%/../../../../../dialog/OptionsDialog.xdl</value>
          </prop>
          <prop oor:name="EventHandlerService">
            <value>org.libreoffice.example.comp.StarterProjectImpl</value>
          </prop>
        </node>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>
</oor:component-data>
```

The problem is that EventHandlerService is not working, if I compile the extension it doesn't create this menu, but if I remove the value of the EventeHandlerServices it show the menu but it doesn't preserve the data.

You can see the source of StarterProjectImpl [here](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension/blob/master/source/org/libreoffice/example/comp/StarterProjectImpl.java)

If someone have any suggestion, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see a file named `OptionsDialog.xcu` in the StarterProjectImpl project.  Are you following an example from somewhere?

There is an example called `OptionsPageDemo` at https://github.com/vmiklos/lo-sdk-examples/tree/master/java/OptionsPageDemo.  I downloaded it from https://github.com/vmiklos/lo-sdk-examples.

Then I opened it in NetBeans and updated the libraries (juh.jar, jurt.jar, ridl.jar, unoil.jar from the LibreOffice folder).  Running and installing in OpenOffice 4.1.2 successfully showed the options screen.  There was an error when trying to save the options, but the part that your question is asking about worked.

This also came up from a google search: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19784.

Comment: Thanks Jim, thats help me, I had a problem with StarterProjectImpl.java, I was missing XContainerWindowEventHandler and some things related to this Event. Thanks again.